# TSQL Window function Count - help counting items with specific values in other columns

Tags: sql, function, t-sql, count, window-functions

I am trying to count the number of times a size appears per store, per item, per color. I have tried the traditional count of the size with a partition for the store, item, and color but it is returning the total count for that size (not specific for the store, item, color).  I have tried to simplify the table I am used to a #Clothes table below:

[image: Example table #Clothes]

The most common size for each item, each color at each store, and the count for it.

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

I would try doing:

```
SELECT *,
COUNT(Size) OVER( PARTITION BY Size, Store, Item, Color) AS Count 
From #Clothes
```

But this would show the entire count for that size (such as 7 for size 34 despite the store, item, or color)

Can someone please share a better way to do window functions that will count the items for each column in the partition by a portion of the function?

Thank you!

[2]: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Aw8L.jpg![enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Aw8L.jpg!%5Benter) image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZ5ue.jpg)[image]

Comment: use `GROUP BY Store, Item, Color, Size`

Comment: Where does `Store` come from?  It is not shown in the sample data.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
STORE
,ITEM
,COLOR
,SIZE
,COUNT(*)
FROM #Clothes
GROUP BY STORE, ITEM, COLOR, SIZE
```

Hopefully I've understood you correctly.

Rather than using PARTITION BY, you should be using GROUP BY.
For example, if you used GROUP BY instead, and include a COUNT(*) in the SELECT, for the row that is STORE = Target, ITEM = Shorts, COLOUR = Green, SIZE = 32 you would get a count of 2 (at least you would for the data that is visible in the image you have provided).

I hope this makes sense and that the code works for you.